# Why does my bandsaw blade track towards the front of the wheel?

Tags: band-saw, blade

After adjusting my bandsaw wheels for coplanarity, my blade will not track towards the center of the wheel. Instead, it creeps towards the front of the wheel. Tilting the top wheel does walk it back a little, but I would like to maintain coplanarity. How can I fix this?

FYI, spinning the wheel in the opposite direction does seem to move the blade to the correct location, but obviously this is not idea because once it moves in the correct direction, the blade tracks towards the front again.

[image: Bandsaw blade tracks towards fronts]

Comment: Sounds like that aren't actually coplanar.

Answer (score 6):

Watching the carter band saw tips and tricks video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGbZqWac0jU) Alex Snodgrass states co-planer is not what you want.
Instead the top wheel and bottom wheel should be canted slightly to the middle and blade tooth side (Top wheel / bottom wheel \ ) and you should be aiming to have the gullet of the blade tracking in the center.  Further back then most recommend.

Based on his video I have tweaked my upper wheel spinning by hand repeatedly and managed to get it pretty centered.  The tires on your wheels are slightly humped in the middle and that's what your teeth should be riding on.

If you can't manage to tweak your upper wheel angle to fix this you may want to look at your tires.  Most saws let you swap these and they do wear out.

Comment: By far my favorite video when it comes to mounting blades on the bandsaw.